# Creating hardlinks in docker container takes long the first time

Tags: performance, docker, hardlink

I am creating hard links of all the files in a directory (some 500MB) in a docker container using following command:

```
cp -al source destination
```

Interestingly, when I issue the above command the first time (i.e. when there is no hardlink for each file in that directory), it takes quite a long time. This is not the case when I issue the above command again to create hardlinks of same files in other destination. This is also not the case when I do that in my docker host (even if it's the first hardlink that is being created).

My docker container uses overlay2 as the storage driver. Here is my `docker info` output

```
Containers: 61
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 60
Images: 142
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc oci
Default Runtime: oci
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version: fbadd789ddf86a4be9d6905528b7486c61e52612 (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: fbadd789ddf86a4be9d6905528b7486c61e52612-dirty (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 4.14.13-300.fc27.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 27 (Workstation Edition)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.58 GiB
Name: pranavk.local.me
ID: STYG:PZCA:FMHL:FLCU:N7VG:Z463:KYQF:QVHO:KWKP:FHTY:EUBA:QBUK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: docker.io (secure), registry.fedoraproject.org (secure), registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)
```

Edit:
If I remove all the hardlinks and then issue above `cp` command again, it's fast again. Phew!

I am not sure what's causing this or from where I should start looking from.